# How can i address to a variable from construct for use in method of same class?

Tags: c++, string, class, vector, constructor

I have this code:

```
class Passport
{
public:
    Passport()
    {
        std::vector<std::string> class_people(people,people+6); 
        std::vector<std::string> class_birth(birth,birth+6);
    }

    void show_data() {
        std::copy(class_people.begin(), class_birth.end());  
    }
};
```

When I try to use `class_people` in `show_data()`, the compiler complains that the variable is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your member functions to access a variable, you need to make it a *member* variable of your class:

```
class Passport {
  std::vector<std::string> class_people; 
  std::vector<std::string> class_birth;

public:
  Passport():
   class_people(people,people+6),
   class_birth(birth,birth+6)
  {}

};
```

Naturally your constructor will need some adaptation (and I assumed `people` and `birth` to be global, as in your code sample).

Comment: It looks like he's also trying to initialize the vectors. Maybe you should add the proper way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that constructor takes initialization arguments

```
    class Passport {
      std::vector<std::string> class_people; 
      std::vector<std::string> class_birth;

    public:
      Passport(const char* people[], const char* birth[])
        : class_people(people,people+sizeof(people)/sizeof(people[0]))
        , class_birth(birth,birth+sizeof(birth)/sizeof(birth[0]))
      {}

};
```